# ICU: Create a case-insensitive collation

Tags: c++, sqlite, icu

I am creating a custom build of SQLite3 and I want to implement case-insensitive text columns.

Is it possible to create a case-insensitive collation?

Comment: What have you tried? What's your precise problem? Obviously case-insensitive collations exist, and ICU supports [far more complex rules](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/customization)

Comment: I have used [ucol_open(const char*, UErrorCode*)](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucol_8h.html#a4721e4c0a519bb0139a874e191223590) A code snippet is available [here](http://ideone.com/XrXKj)

Comment: According to the ICU docs you want the collation option (CLDR) `caseLevel`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to call [ucol_setStrength](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucol_8h.html#adcbb3eee538142a06a89e066400dd9b7)  with `UCOL_PRIMARY` or `UCOL_SECONDARY` weight.  Try out something like [this demo](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=lt&d_=en&x=col&str=x)